# How to get backbone model attributes without .get

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

In backbone it seems that I have to get model attributes via `model.get('att_name')`

I'd prever to get them the way I'd get any public field within an object: `model.att_name`

Can anyone think of a way to get around this?

eg: In python world I would override getattr on the model something like this:

```
def getattr(self, att):
   return self.get(att)
```

Oh, and I'm using CoffeeScript

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Model attributes that you use `get()` and `set()` or `defaults` to get/set are stored in the `instance.attributes` attribute.

Also, these are the attributes that are going to be passed to and returned from `sync()` as well as `toJSON()`. So when you `fetch()`, `save()` etc, only what is stored in `instance.attributes` gets passed along.

Nothing will stop you of course from having normal attributes like `instance.foo` on your objects. If you want to treat those as the other attributes and pass these along to `fetch()` and `save()` you can do so by providing a custom `parse()` on your model which by default does nothing. That said, you should only do this if you really deem it absolutely necessary, if only to comply to the Backbone conventions.

Comment: What if I did something like this in initialize: `for att in @attributes: @[att] = ()->@get(att)` ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't speak coffescript. I *guess* that means this[attr] = this.get(attr). That will not intercept any further attribute manipulation through sync, set. Additionally it will only give you getters, but not setters.

Comment: Ah sorry, equiv is this: `this[att] = function(){this.get(att)}` ...so I could do `model.get('att')` via `model.att()` ...not ideal, but I'm hoping you can tell me whether this will break any of Backbone's functionality. And thanks btw.

Comment: Sure this will work. As a getter of course not as a setter, and you will still miss whatever attributes are not yet set. I would still avoid it, not because it violates something, but because it won't work with say attributes that are not set in init.

Comment: Understood. Looks like toJSON is probably my best option for getting the syntax I want in my templates then. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You could do `this[att] = function(val) { return typeof(val) == "undefined" ? this.get(att) : this.set(att, val); }`. Still would only work when a model has been retrieved from a backend (E.g. a new model won't have any initial attributes, so won't work). There's probably some performance overhead as well.

Answer (score 4):

The attributes are accessible at [`Model.attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes). You can read directly from that, but use `set` to change them. You can also get a representation of all your attributes from [`Model.toJSON()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) (*note:* `toJSON()` doesn't actually return JSON, but a javascript object).

The recommended way is to use `toJSON()` for templates, serialization etc.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't away around this, really. You could use `model.attributes.att_name`, but that's probably not what you want.

JavaScript doesn't have (at least not in all browsers) the ability to redirect access of properties.